# Passing a socket from Python select's read list into another function

Tags: python, sockets

I am using Python's `select` library to asynchronously read data off of two sockets. Since the size of the packets that I receive can vary, and I don't know if there is a maximum possible size for the data that I am reading, I have implemented a function called `recvAll(sock)` to get all of the data off of a socket:

```
def recvAll(sock):
    buffer = ''
    data = []

    try:
        while True:
            buffer = sock.recv(8192)
            if not buffer:
                break
            data.append(buffer)
    except error, (errorCode, message):
        if errorCode != 10035:
            print 'error: ', str(errorCode), ' ', message
    return "".join(data)
```

I am calling the select library like this:

```
rlist, wlist, elist = select.select([sock1, sock2], [], [])
for sock in rlist:
    if sock == sock1:
        #data1 = sock.recv(8192)
        data1 = recvAll(sock)
    else:
        #data2 = sock.recv(8192)
        data2 = recvAll(sock)
```

In the for loop for each socket I process, if I call `sock.recv` directly, I am able to properly get data1 and data2. However, if I first pass `sock` to `recvAll` I am only able to get data1. It does not appear that `recvAll` is being called on `sock2` at all. Why is this the case?

Comment: You have some spacing issues. Can you fix them?

Comment: You would have to use async to get data simultaneously from both socks. Your if statement returns `True` on first check and thats why you only get that. Also your function will not return unless the stream ends so your `for loop` never gets to the second check.

Comment: Another thing us that buffer will not be appended if your while loop breaks. You will lose some data.

Comment: @Mick there is some dead time between messages. I thought `sock.recv` would return an error if it attempts to read data and there is nothing to read?

Comment: Yes but your loop breaks before the buffer gets appended to `data`. `if not buffer: break` will break out of the `while loop` all together so you don't get to check for exceptions or append anything to data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely what is going on is that, since your socket is not set as non-blocking ( `socket.setblocking(0)` ),  your `recvAll` function is blocking, waiting for more input from the socket.  It won't return 0 until the socket is closed by the other end, or an error occurs.

The way to fix this is to structure your code to combine the functions of `recvAll` with your `select`.  Each time your select returns with an indication that there is data waiting on the socket, read from the socket ONLY ONCE, append the data to the buffer for that socket, then loop back into `select`.

After each `recv`, look at what you got and decide what to do next.. eg. for some protocols, if the buffer contains a `\n`, that would be an indication that you got a complete message and need to do something with it.  Or, in your case, it seems that closing of the socket is the indication that your message is complete.. so you should look for `recv` returning a zero length string....

If the socket was in fact closed, then you need to remove it from the list of sockets you are passing into `select`.